# Change url estructure htacesss

Tags: hyperlink

I've been trying for days to generate a file that modifies the url structure.

I have a current url like this

http://localhost/stores/leo

and I need it to stay like this

https://leo.localhost

Use PHP Server XAMP and Larabel

the word "leo" is generated according to the product and it will always change.

How could you generate it?
Thanks!

I have this code that works but the URL changes in the address bar and does not stay with the desired URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#force https and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# profile redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.localhost [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://localhost/stores/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This will be dependent on your programming language and possibly webserver. We can't help you if you don't share what kind of technology you are using, and you should ideally also share what you tried so far.

Comment: Use PHP server XAMP and LARABEL thanks!

Comment: Edit the question with the code that works however it changes the URL and does not keep by the desired URL